# Joint probability simplifies to 0?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

There are three ways I am aware of for expanding the joint probability of two events:

1. p(x and y) = p(x) + p(y) - p(x or y)             (for mutually exclusive events)
   = p(x) + p(y) - (p(x) + p(y) = 0? This part confused me because it always is 0, but maybe I'm mixing up the rules for independent vs dependent.
2. p(x and y) = p(x) * p(y)                          (for independent events)
3. p(x and y) = p(x|y) * p(y) = p(y|x) * p(x)
   = [(p(x and y))/p(y)] * p(y) = p(x and y)
   Here for the third step, we run into the same problem where it simplifies back to itself.
   I am particularly confused on method 1 and 3. The first method can simplify to 0, which doesn't seem right. The third can't really be expanded because it simplifies back to itself immediately, and the expansion is useless.
   Is there any way to expand p(x and y) using only p(x), p(y) and p(x|y) or p(y|x)?
   Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: On 1, if $X$ and $Y$ are mutually exclusive, then they can't happen at the same time. So, you'd expect $P(X \text{ and } Y)$ to be 0, exactly like you've shown. On 3, you can't really break down the expression any more past $P(X|Y)P(Y)$ (unless you start using probabilty density functions). What you've shown is expected.

Comment: I see. Thanks. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

In general:

- $\mathbb P(X \text{ or } Y) = \mathbb P(X ) +\mathbb P(Y)-\mathbb P(X \text{ and  } Y)$
- $\mathbb P(X \text{ and } Y) = \mathbb P(X ) +\mathbb P(Y)-\mathbb P(X \text{ or } Y)$
- $\mathbb P(X \text{ and } Y) = \mathbb P(X \mid Y ) \,\mathbb P(Y)= \mathbb P(Y \mid X )\,\mathbb P(X)$

For mutually exclusive events

- $\mathbb P(X \text{ and  } Y)=0 $ so
- $\mathbb P(X \text{ or } Y) = \mathbb P(X ) +\mathbb P(Y)$
- $\mathbb P(X \mid Y ) =0 $
- $\mathbb P(Y \mid X )=0$

For independent events

- $\mathbb P(X \text{ and } Y)=\mathbb P(X)\,\mathbb P(Y) $ so
- $\mathbb P(X \text{ or } Y) =\mathbb P(X ) +\mathbb P(Y) - \mathbb P(X)\,\mathbb P(Y) = 1-(1-\mathbb P(X))\,(1-\mathbb P(Y))$
- $\mathbb P(X \mid Y ) =\mathbb P(X ) $
- $\mathbb P(Y \mid X )=\mathbb P(Y )$

Comment: Thank you so much Henry. This actually clears up an extended version of a related question I had posted somewhere else. May I ask for a reference for this line?   P(X or Y)=P(X)+P(Y)−P(X)P(Y)=1−(1−P(X))(1−P(Y)). I haven't seen this anywhere else.

Comment: @LoganGrove The first equality just applies the previous line to the first general point.  The second equality can either be seen by multiplying out, or by saying it is not the case that neither $X$ nor $Y$ happen